# Problems printing Web tables and graphs to pdf with window.print()

Tags: css, reactjs, printing

I have a page showing tables (of different lengths depending on data shown) and a graph under, and I'm having a lot of issues getting a consistent quality depending on amount of data and whether it's chrome and firefox. My client is having similar but different issues, making it harder to problem solve as I can't recreate the viewing issues that they're experiencing.

This might be a fuzzy summary but I'm at wits end trying to find a solution and am just unable to get my browsers to behave.

Problems are:

- thead and tfoot does not repeat on new pages on firefox (for me, but not for my client. They're experiencing the same problem but with chrome instead). My firefox doesn't even seem to realize that page breaks are occuring. I have set `display: table-header-group` on thead and `display: table-footer-group` on tfoot. I have set `display: table-row-group; break-inside: auto` on tbody. My firefox will just render the table in one long "stream", sometimes with a page break in the middle of a table row, even tho I've sen `tr { break-inside: avoid; break-after: auto }`
- The graphs are sometimes printed over two pages, instead of having a page break before rendering. It's created with html canvas, and I have given it the prop `break-inside: avoid`. If it is pushed to a new page, the space height that is blank on the previous page is then unrendered for the bottom of the graph on the next page. It seems like even if the graph has a preceding page break, the renderer does not know it and will only render the height starting from the previous page, and stop rendering even if there's more content to render. I have "solved" this by adding a constant margin-bottom to the graph, but this often results in an extra blank page.

The page is a react app with css (with @media print rules) accompanying each component. All component's css is applied, I have tried changing font sizes and similar and they are working correctly, but some rules (break-inside etc) seem to be ignored.

Bonus question: On searching I am finding many bug reports for different browsers when it comes to web printing. It seems like support for printing web pages isn't prioritised among browsers, which leads me to wonder if it's worth the trouble or if I should try to find an alternative solution all together.